# Oracle - Update NCLOB after insert

Tags: java, oracle, sql-insert

I use Oracle 11g, I found old code which should insert record to table

The code insert all values except NCLOB column and only if value exists (can be null) it then update the specific column (using `PreparedStatement setCharacterStream()`).

I want to change this code to one insert, but want to make sure there's no good reason to keep this flow - update after insert for specific NCLOB column?

Code (PreparedStatement ps and ps2):

```
ps = conn.prepareStatement(INSERT_RECORD);
//INSERT INTO DATA_RECORDS (ID) VALUES (?) and other values...
ps.setInt(1, id);
result = ps.executeUpdate() == 1;
if (data != null && result) {
   StringReader reader = new StringReader(data);
   ps2 = conn.prepareStatement(UPDATE_RECORD); 
   //UPDATE DATA_RECORDS SET DATA = ? WHERE ID = ?
   ps2.setCharacterStream(1, reader, data.length());
   ps.setInt(2, id);
            ...
   ps2.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Firstly post your old code and secondly you can look for Merge statement,

Comment: added code sample

Comment: I _assume_ this was done to avoid the overhead of sending a large NCLOB over the wire if there is a chance that the row already exists. Otherwise the NCLOB could be included directly sent as part of the the `INSERT` statement.

Comment: and if row exists it will throw an exception? Is it better to check it exists by id first?

Comment: This depends on how the insert query is written - but you have not shown that code. However: _if_ the insert did throw an exception, the code after the `executeUpdate()` (especially the update) would never be executed.

Comment: Added more code of SQLs

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think you answer it on comments, can you provide an answer?